# Can't get inputtext value on ajax after they change

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get a value from an inputtext typed inside a datatable column and update an outputtext from other column with the multiply of this inputtext value and other inputtext value. My problem is that I can't get the value typed when ajax is called because I'm getting the previous value from the field that receive the value (gasto.valor), not the current value typed. This is my code:

**XHTML**

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{cadastroContasBean.dataTable}" var="gasto"
             value="#{cadastroContasBean.listaGasto}" scrollable="true"
             scrollHeight="150" editable="true" editMode="cell" id="Tabela"
             widgetVar="wTabela">
    <p:column headerText="Nome">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{gasto.nome}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{gasto.nome}" style="width:96%" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Quantidade">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{gasto.quantidade}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="inputQtd" value="#{gasto.quantidade}"
                             style="width:96%" onkeydown="MascaraNumero()"
                             onkeyup="MascaraNumero()">
                    <p:ajax  event="blur" render="outputVT" listener="#{cadastroContasBean.atualizaVT}"  execute="inputQtd" process="@this" immediate="true"/>
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Valor">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{gasto.valor}">
                    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />

                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="inputValor" value="#{gasto.valor}"
                             style="width:96%" onkeyup="mascara(this, valor)"
                             onkeydown="mascara(this, valor)">
                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00"></f:convertNumber>
                    <f:validator validatorId="MoedaValidator" />
                    <p:ajax  event="blur" render="outputVT" listener="#{cadastroContasBean.atualizaVT}"  execute="inputValor" process="@this" immediate="true" >
                    </p:ajax>
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Valor Total" id="vt">
        <h:outputText id="outputVT" value="#{gasto.valorTotal}">
            <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

MB

```
public void atualizaVT(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

    Gastos gastoDataTableAtual = ((Gastos)dataTable.getRowData());

    if(!event.getComponent().getId().equals("inputQtd")){
        BigDecimal valorAtual = (BigDecimal)((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue();
        gastoDataTableAtual.setValorTotal(valorAtual.multiply(new BigDecimal(((Gastos)dataTable.getRowData()).getQuantidade())));
        Iterator<Gastos> gastosAsIterator = listaGasto.iterator();
        while (gastosAsIterator.hasNext()){
            Gastos it = gastosAsIterator.next();
            int id = 0;
            if(it.getId() == gastoDataTableAtual.getId()){
                //listaGasto.get(id).setValor(gastoDataTableAtual.getValor());
                listaGasto.get(id).setValorTotal(gastoDataTableAtual.getValorTotal());
                ((Gastos)dataTable.getRowData()).setValorTotal(gastoDataTableAtual.getValorTotal());
                break;
            }
            id++;
        }
    }else{
        Integer valorAtual = (Integer)((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue();
        gastoDataTableAtual.setValorTotal(((Gastos)dataTable.getRowData()).getValor().multiply(new BigDecimal(valorAtual)));
        Iterator<Gastos> gastosAsIterator = listaGasto.iterator();
        int id = 0;
        while (gastosAsIterator.hasNext()){
            Gastos it = gastosAsIterator.next();
            if(it.getId() == gastoDataTableAtual.getId()){
                //listaGasto.get(id).setQuantidade(gastoDataTableAtual.getQuantidade());
                listaGasto.get(id).setValorTotal(gastoDataTableAtual.getValorTotal());
                ((Gastos)dataTable.getRowData()).setValorTotal(gastoDataTableAtual.getValorTotal());
                break;
            }
            id++;
        }
```

I understant that ajax event "blur" is called before "gasto.valor" is changed, but when I change the ajax event to "change" the method "atualizaVT" is not called. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 0):

"change" event is not an AjaxBehaviorEvent.
Try to  implement atualizaVT without argument
In this way:

public void atualizaVT(){

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't work. When I edit the inputtext only validator is called. Anyway, I need to get the  inputtext  content and, without arguments, I don't know how I do it.

Comment: We use selection parameter in datatable selection="#{actionBean.selectedData}"
In this way, when you select an row and send  ajax request, the selectedData will be filled with the current value.

Comment: It worked, but I did it another way: I created an inputtext with getters and setters in the managebean class and binded with the inputtext in the XHTML view. Then got the value with "inputtext.getValue()" in the "atualizaVT() method called by event="change" on ajax. Thanks for the help! –